# How to use the activated route's data DIRECTLY in the HTML template containing the RouterOutlet?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular8

*This one took me a while to figure out, so I hope to save someone's time by sharing the solution in the SO's Q&A way. Here it goes:*

## Goal

I have an Angular8 web application, where I use the [RouterModule](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterModule) to navigate between the components.

Here is how my routes are defined:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'moo', component: AppMooComponent, data: { title: 'Moo Section', desc: 'Moo is the first example component.' } },
    { path: 'boo', component: AppBooComponent, data: { title: 'Boo Section', desc: 'Boo is the second example component.' } },
    { path: 'foo', component: AppFooComponent, data: { title: 'Foo Section', desc: 'Foo is the third example component.' } },
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'moo', pathMatch: 'full' },
];
```

I would like to be able to use `data.title` and `data.desc` (or any defined data for that matter) in my HTML template in the following way:

```
<ul>
    <li><a [routerLink]="['moo']">Moo</a></li>
    <li><a [routerLink]="['boo']">Boo</a></li>
    <li><a [routerLink]="['foo']">Foo</a></li>
</ul>
<hr>
<h1>{{<something>.data.title}}</h1>
<p>{{<something>.data.desc}}</p>
<hr>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

## Problem

Injecting `ActivatedRoute` to get the data does not work, because `ActivatedRoute` is:

> [A service that is provided to each route component](https://angular.io/guide/router)

and the component, containing the `router-outlet` is not a route component.

## Research

I have searched the site and found the following questions discussing a very similar problem:

[How can I access an activated child route's data from the parent route's component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43806188/how-can-i-access-an-activated-child-routes-data-from-the-parent-routes-compone)

[Get route data outside the router outlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47581750/get-route-data-outside-the-router-outlet)

[Access activated route data from some other component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41613750/access-activated-route-data-from-some-other-component)

[Accessing Route data in root component, route data is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38460470/accessing-route-data-in-root-component-route-data-is-empty)

[Angular ActivatedRoute data returns an empty object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45737375/angular-activatedroute-data-returns-an-empty-object)

However, in my case the emphasize is on **direct usage of the route's data in the HTML template**, so neither of those possible solutions is suitable (as summarized in [How To Get Route Path Parameters In Non-Routed Angular Components](https://medium.com/@tomastrajan/how-to-get-route-path-parameters-in-non-routed-angular-components-32fc90d9cb52)):

- Moving the non-routed component inside of the routed component
- Using router navigation events
- Creating an additional service to hold the route path param state and make it available for all other interested components

---

How to achieve that in the desired way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Solution

I would suggest you to use a [template variable reference](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterOutlet#template-variable-references) as shown in the documentation:

> `#myTemplateVar="outlet"`

Then you can access the route's data via the [`activatedRouteData: Data`](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterOutlet#activatedRouteData) property of `<router-outlet>` and use it in the HTML template like this:

```
<h1>{{myTemplateVar.activatedRouteData.title}}</h1>
<p>{{myTemplateVar.activatedRouteData.desc}}</p>
<hr>
<router-outlet #myTemplateVar="outlet"></router-outlet>
```

## Example

I have prepared a simple example for you on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/get-activated-route-data) in order to demonstrate the proposed solution.

## Result

Here how the result looks like (it is similar for the other routes/components):

[image: Component Moo loaded and the route's data is displayed]

Comment: I like this solution @scopchanov but how would you do this with data in child routes?

Comment: @IvoOostwegel, I think you should post a new question, explaining the use case you have in mind.